# In Perlin noise, why need vectors and how to use them exactly?

Tags: noise

I'm reading this tutorial on Perlin noise:
http://www.angelcode.com/dev/perlin/perlin.html
which seems to be the clearest one but still not perfect. A lot of details are skipped and a lot of code unexplained.

My general question is, why do we need vectors for Perlin noise (instead of just noise values at specific coordinates), why do they have to be unit vectors and how do we combine them with the given input point coordinates?

Also, the article gives this piece of code as vector calculation which looks like trying to find out square cell coordinates (except 1 is subtracted instead of being added for some reason):

```
// Computing vectors from the four points to the input point
float tx0 = x - floorf(x);
float tx1 = tx0 - 1;

float ty0 = y - floorf(y);
float ty1 = ty0 - 1;
```

This doesn't look like any vector operation.

Comment: There's no in memory vector in the code snippet, but there are logical vectors `<tx0, tx1>` and `<ty0, ty1>` which give the offset from the lower-left point in the integer plane. I'm no expert, but it looks like the point of using vectors is that it allows you smooth the noise (the random unit vectors anchored to the integer plain) to get smooth noise over the plane.

Comment: but it's the bi-cubic interpolation which smooths the noise out. why use vectors for interpolation instead of just taking pixel values from some specific coordinates?

Comment: @Val_Cool, I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "taking pixel values from some specific coordinates". The vectors are defined over a blank plane, so there are no pixel values in that case.

Comment: i meant, why not create a random-noised bitmap and use each pixel as the integer points for the final noise's grid cell? and then just interpolate those values instead of doing all these complicated calculations on vectors

Comment: I would suggest writing such an algorithm yourself. The result, depending on how you do the interpolation, will look like [blurred noise](http://www.squaregear.net/gimptips/worn14.png) and not the famous Perlin noise.

Comment: that is exactly what i need to do, hence my attempt to understand the algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Perlin Noise is a concept in maths. If you can imagine a sectional of a mountain range, you would get a, relative, smooth motion, like a distorted sin wave. The concept is that each position, (x, y) location is relative to its "neighbor." This is the idea with the vectors. Vectors are a direction, not a static point. So, the vector is used to provide a smooth transition between points. It provides a general direction of the lines. Otherwise you would wind up with something that looks like a stock market graph. A bitmap with random gradient values will most likely have no transitions - it would not make sense.

Picture what that random gradient value bitmap would look like as a height-map. Verticies of a mesh will be chaotic. Huge increases and decreases with no general flow.

Answer (score 1):

The vectors represent slopes, pointing uphill or downhill. The more they point toward a point, the more this point will be boosted respectively. This helps remove grid bias, ensures that perlin noise is comprised entirely of gradients, and results in a circular appearance overall.

(the less circular looking perlin noise is due to octaves)